# Tornado + Mustache templating on client side

Tags: django, templates, tornado, mustache

Is there any way to force tornado skip variables in part of template?

I want something like this:

**Template**:

```
{{ block render_me }} 
   {% for var in range(1,3) %}
       {{ var }} 
   {% end %}
{{ end }}
{{ block render_me_later }} 
   {% magic_no_replace_vars_word %}
   <script id="mustacheTemplate"> 
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">{{#items}}<li>{{item}}</li>{{/items}}</ul>
   </script> 
   {% end %}
{{ end }}
```

**Output**:

```
1 2 3
<script id="mustacheTemplate"> 
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">{{#items}}<li>{{item}}</li>{{/items}}</ul>
</script>
```

Same solution for `django` are also welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Tornado, you can use `{{!` to output `{{`, and `{%!` for `{%`. Closing tags should work literally, if there's no open tag.

In Django, as Chris Pratt metioned, you can use `{% templatetag openvariable %}var{% templatetag closevariable %}` for `{{var}}`. Since that sucks, if you're doing anything more than a page or two it's probably worth backporting the `verbatim` template tag as supervacuo suggested.

Comment: Wow! Very elegant solution for `tornado`! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Tornado, but for Django you probably want [the `{% verbatim %}` template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#verbatim):

**Input**

```
{% block render_me %}
{% for var in range(1,3) %}
    {{ var }} 
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
{% block render_me_later %} 
   {% verbatim %}
   <script id="mustacheTemplate"> 
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">{{#items}}<li>{{item}}</li>{{/items}}</ul>
   </script> 
   {% endverbatim %}
{% endblock %}
```

**Output**

```
1 2 3
<script id="mustacheTemplate"> 
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">{{#items}}<li>{{item}}</li>{{/items}}</ul>
</script>
```

Unfortunately, it hasn't yet made it into a released version (it's planned for 1.5) — either use the development version of Django, back-port the added template tag yourself, or use something like [`django-templatetag-handlebars`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-templatetag-handlebars) to implement it for you until you can upgrade.

Comment: There's also the `templatetag` template tag, which is more verbose than `verbatim`, but can be used right now and in legacy code, without any 3rd-party extensions: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#templatetag

Comment: So you're saying OP should replace each mustache opening and closing bracket with `{% templatetag openvariable %}` and `{% templatetag closevariable %}`? "More verbose" seems like something of an understatement...

Comment: The OP can do whatever he wants to do. It's a possibility, and he should know about it.